# How to see the list of unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, sonarqube

We would like to display unit test results of our C# project on SonarQube. Unfortunately, we get only the display of how many tests have been running.

[image]

When we try to display the list of those tests, the list is empty.

[image]

We get a `result.trx` file used in SonarQube with `/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=$svstestpath` as an argument to `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe`.
SonarQube seems to display the counters properties of this `.trx` file, but only that.

We don't know if there is another thing to set on the C# Plugin or anywhere else, the building script seems to be fine as we get the display of test running number.

How can I see the list of test files?